# Dotenv process.env keys are not accessible until I make a copy of the object

Tags: node.js, express, dotenv

I'm adding .env to my Node Express app and when I do:

```
console.log(process.env)
```

I see some default process env variables which I didn't add, and also the one custom variable I've added to my .env file (TEST_VAR):

```
{ 
  npm_package_devDependencies_nodemon: '^1.11.0',
  npm_config_version_tag_prefix: 'v',
  TEST_VAR: '12345'
}
```

However when on the very next line I do:

```
console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR)
```

I get:

```
undefined
```

However, running this:

```
console.log(process.env.npm_package_devDependencies_nodemon)
```

Returns the expected:

```
'^1.11.0'
```

I was able to solve this with:

```
var envVars = { ... process.env }
console.log(envVars.TEST_VAR)
```

Which actually output the value set in my .env file.

Can anybody shed some light on why I need to make a copy before I'm able to access the variables that appear to be present?

Answer (score 0):

[dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) requires `.env` files to be in a specific format, and it [doesn't include JSON](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv).

It look more like `VARIABLE_KEY=VARIABLE_VALUE`. In your case it will look like this

```
npm_package_devDependencies_nodemon=^1.11.0
npm_config_version_tag_prefix=v
TEST_VAR=12345
```

Comment: Sorry, if my post was unclear, my .env file contains only a single line that looks like this: `TEST_VAR=12345`
The JSON looking object you're seeing is the result of running the line: `console.log(process.env)`